# how to set header "burger" in react-navigation in each stack without duplicate it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

i build a stack navigator and i want to add burger to all the screens.
right not its work but i pass header for every screen ant it look Clumsy and illegible and overly duplicated

**the question** there is a way to shortcut or pass it one time (maybe in the Stack.navigator?)
example from my code:
(look at this lines: headerLeft: () =>< AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,)

```
const StackNavigator = ({ navigation }) => (
<Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen" navigationOptions screenOptions={stackScreenOptions}>
    <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainScreen}
        headerMode="screen"
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="MainScreen"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        options={{
            title: "meetings",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
        name="MeetingPicker"
        component={MeetingPicker}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
        name="UserHistory"
        component={UserHistory}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="MyMeetings"
        component={UserHistory}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="About"
        component={AboutScreen}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
        name="Location"
        component={LocationScreen}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="Logout"
        component={LogoutModal}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => <AnimateHamburger navigation={navigation} />,
        }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  );

   export default StackNavigator;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass it to `screenOptions` with your `stackScreenOptions` in your code here:

```
<Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen" navigationOptions screenOptions={stackScreenOptions}>
```

Take a look at the react-navigation docs about this:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/#screenoptions-prop-on-the-navigator

Comment: But there is no way to put inside it a component like button or something like that... only some props...

Comment: No, `screenOptions` allows you to pass components in it, jut try to do it like this for example:
`const stackScreenOptions = () => ({ headerLeft: () => <YourComponent /> }) ... <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={stackScreenOptions} /> ...`

Comment: Thabk u so much. I will try it.

Comment: now my problem that i not get the "navigation" props and the opeDrawer props to the animateHmaburger component... ? how can i get it?

Comment: you can use `useNavigation` hook inside your `burger` component and access `openDrawer` method with it